# Refresh/Reload Application scope managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem to refresh or reload an application scoped managed bean. It behaves as cached data bean. So once data is changed on db side, i want to reload the the list in the bean. 
Is there anyway to refresh/reload the list,  say once a day based on given time? 
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add a method to the aplication scoped bean which does exactly that.

```
public void reload() {
    list = dao.list();
}
```

Then grab/inject this bean in another bean and call the method.

```
data.reload();
```

---

**Update** sorry, I overlooked the "once a day" bit. You mean automatic reloading in the background? This is best to be achieved by a background thread which is managed by [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Create a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) like follows:

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Reloader reloader = new Reloader(event.getServletContext());
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(reloader, 1, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Where the class `Reloader` look like this (assuming that the managed bean name is `data`)

```
public class Reloader implements Runnable {

    private ServletContext context;

    public Reloader(ServletContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Data data = (Data) context.getAttribute("data");
        if (data != null) {
            data.reload();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You have however to be extremely careful with managing threads yourself in a servletcontainer. The `scheduler.shutdownNow();` bit in `contextDestroyed()` is very important. You may consider delegating the thread management job to the servletcontainer, if it supports it. JBoss has for example Quartz for this, Glassfish has for example `WorkManager` for this. In Tomcat, the above example is your best bet.

Comment: @BalusC I have the same need. I implemented this in my application. The only one problem is that in `Reloader` method `run()` my bean is always null. Can u give me a hint please