# Load Applicationscoped Bean with ServletContext

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jboss

I have created a class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener. Inside

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
```

I create a timer which will be executed every 30 seconds. Inside this timer I want to set a parameter from my @ApplicationScoped - Bean in order to display the information from the timer to my website.

Here is what I did so far:

**StartupListener.java**

```
package de.whatever;

import java.util.Timer;
import javax.naming.Context;

public class CargoServiceStartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {

    ....        

        ModuleScannerTask task = new ModuleScannerTask(contextEvent.getServletContext());
        Timer timer = new Timer("Scanner");
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 10000);
```

**ModuleScannerTask.java**

```
package de.whatever;

import java.util.Enumeration;

public class ModuleScannerTask extends TimerTask{

private ServletContext context;

public ModuleScannerTask (ServletContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run() {
      System.out.println("Start scanning ...");
          ...
```

**ModuleBean.java**

```
package de.whatever;

@ManagedBean (name="modOverview")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ModuleOverviewBean {

private String randomData;
```

My question is how to set data into **randomData** field in my application bean.

I read that I could load the attribute "modOverview" from the ServletContext, but that returns null.

What would be the correct way to load and set the values?

I am using JBoss (without spring).

Thanks
Hauke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it returns `null` then it simply means that JSF hasn't created it yet. Just create one yourself. JSF won't override it when already present in application scope. You just have to be aware that any managed properties of this class won't be set automatically.

```
ModuleOverviewBean bean = (ModuleOverviewBean) servletContext.getAttribute("modOverview");

if (bean == null) {
    bean = new ModuleOverviewBean();
    servletContext.setAttribute("modOverview", bean);
}

// ...
```

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, the `java.util.Timer` is a very bad way of doing the background job in a Java EE application. Look at least at [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), or since you're already using JBoss, a [`@Singleton`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) EJB with a [`@Schedule`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) method.

#### See also:

- [Refresh/Reload Application scope managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897212/refresh-reload-application-scope-managed-bean)
- [Background timer task in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357033/background-timer-task-in-jsp-web-application)

---

**Update**: if setting of managed properties is also your concern, you could also try to annotate the managed bean with `eager=true` as follows so that JSF will autocreate it on webapp's startup:

```
@ManagedBean(name="modOverview", eager=true)
```

I'm only not entirely sure if this will run before your `ServletContextListener` runs. I think it will. However, it will definitely work if you're using a `@Singleton` EJB with `@Schedule`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the information. I will take a look through that. But the bean problem works.