# I am trying to run this first Spring program using XML and I am getting following error. I am novice in this, Please guide me

Tags: java, spring

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle= (Triangle) applicationContext.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();
    }
}

public class Triangle {
    public void draw()
    {
        System.out.println("Triangle Class");
    }
}
```

> This is the Java program.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="Triangle"/>
</beans>
```

> This is the XML File.
> And When I am trying to run this program, I am getting the following error

*14:32:12.644 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@721e0f4f
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
at practice.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:333)
... 13 more*

> I have also used this code in XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="triangle" class="Triangle"/>
</beans
```

> Then also I am getting the same error

Guide me to do this spring programming perfectly.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897212/refresh-reload-application-scope-managed-bean

Answer (score 0):

It is because you do not start the Spring container yet. You have to call `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.refresh()` to start it.

Another things is that you do not configure the location of the XML configuration file too.

So assuming the XML configuration file is called `config.xml` , please change to the following :

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
applicationContext.setConfigLocations("config.xml");
applicationContext.refresh();
```

Or simply :

```java
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
```

which will call `refresh()` automatically under the cover.

Comment: I have done that but still it is showing errors, And the XML file is in also correct classpath

Comment: @Ajay9 please add the update to your question rather than update the question directly. Because it causes my answer does not match with your question after you update it directly , and cause some guy to downvote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure Ken, Thanks for letting me know Ken!!

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file is in a wrong directory. `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` searches for it on the Java [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath). Java classpath purpose is to locate available compiled class files, but it became very common to place runtime configuration files there too.

If you use Maven to build your project, you can place your `Spring.xml` file into the `src/main/resources`. Maven will copy its contents into the folder which will be on classpath during execution.

Comment: Tried as you said, still it is showing the error

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Community Edition, Tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Find your project folder on disk, archive it and upload it to Google Drive or something.